# jQuery button debugging - determine what is causing navigation/postback event

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dom, jquery-events

I have a jQuery UI button that is being used inside of a jqGrid column. This button is disabled until the `onSelectRow` event is triggered and the corresponding button for the row is enabled.

This button when generated looks something like this (psudocode).

```
<button id=\"" + ids[i] + "_SaveButton\" class=\"SaveButton\" onclick=\"return false;\">Save</button>

$(".SaveButton").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-check' }, text: false, disabled: true }).css({ width: "45px" });

onSelectRow: function () {
     $("#" + _LastSel + "_SaveButton").button("disable");
     $("#" + ID + "_SaveButton").button("enable");
}
```

This button must return false to prevent a postback of the page occurring.

My problem lies in that somewhere in all my code when the `onSelectRow` event is triggering I am getting a postback occurring.

Interestingly this only occurs when the `onSelectRow` is triggered from the column that contains the save button but I digress.

**Basically what I am hoping is someone can give me an idea of how I might determine what event and from which DOM element is triggering the postback. I have attempted to use the `jQuery.unload()` event but this does not provide information regarding what triggered it (at least from what I can see looking thru the eventData object).**

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: not sure but on the grid event you can try `$(".SaveButton").button('enable')` and of course disable when not needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery or jqGrid bug in internet explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162259/jquery-or-jqgrid-bug-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the events is bubbling up to the form, causing submit.  Probably from the way you're binding onSelectRow--try adding an event.preventDefault() in there.

Also hooking the form submit event, then examining event.originalEvent and event.originalTarget.

Also, I recommend against mixing onclick attributes with modern jQuery behavior binding.