# jQuery or jqGrid bug in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

Looking at the following example of the jqGrid

http://members.iinet.net.au/~maximg1/Demo/jqGridBug.htm

(UserName: PublicAccess, Password: 12345678)

You will notice that the option buttons are disabled by default and enabled on the selected row click:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (ID, event) {
    $("#" + _LastSelectedRow + "_SaveButton").button("disable");
    $("#" + _LastSelectedRow + "_DeleteButton").button("disable");
    $("#" + ID + "_SaveButton").button("enable").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#" + ID + "_DeleteButton").button("enable").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
    });
    _LastSelectedRow = ID;
}
```

You will also notice that in the original declared wireup for the buttons they are disabled and wiredup to prevent postbacks:

```
$(".DeleteButton").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-closethick' }, text: false,
     disabled: true }).css({ width: "45px" }).click(function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
});
$(".SaveButton").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-check' }, text: false,
     disabled: true }).css({ width: "45px" }).click(function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
});
```

The behaviour is exactly as expected in both firefox and chrome but good old IE issues a postback when the **ROW THAT IS NOT SELECTED** is clicked **IN THE BUTTON COLUMN**. The behaviour is as expected when clicking one of the other columns such as the description.

I can not work out why this is happening and would be forever in debt to anyone who could shed some light on this situation.

PS: I am aware that I am wiring up event handlers for the buttons twice in two different points and this was only done as a last ditch attempt to resolve the problem (obviously didn’t work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you don't specify the `type` attribute of the buttons which you created. The default value are different in different browsers. If the type is `submit` you will have additional problem. There are some known problems with disabling of the submit buttons. I am not sure that you **really** need any submit at all. Probably just your custom `click` event handler will be enough. If you do need submit, then you can use buttons with the `type="button"`, but call the form submit

```
$("#form1").submit();
```

inside of the `click` event handle. The modified version of your code you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/IEBug.htm). I call `$("#form1").submit()` only inside of the `click` event handle of the "Save" button and not for the "Delete" button. One more disadvantage of the form submit will be reloading the page and removing selection of the grid.

Moreover in [the modified version of the your code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/IEBug.htm) I fixed some small, but important errors and made some small code improvements:

1. You original code loaded some JavaScripts of jqGrid **twice** because of the usage of [grid.loader.js](http://members.iinet.net.au/~maximg1/Demo/grid.loader.js) additionally to other [development scripts](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation).
2. The original code used `ui.multiselect.js` and `jquery.searchFilter.js` which **needed to load** `jquery.searchFilter.css` and `ui.multiselect.css` also.
3. You HTML page should include `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the page header.
4. You can load the data of the jqGrid more effectively and easy using of [data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter of jqGrid instead of the usage of `addRowData` method.
5. Instead of the usage of `localReader: {id: 'ID'}` you can use `key:true` option for the `ID` column. It is better to read and it works with all `datatype` values and not only with the local data.
6. Inside of `beforeSelectRow` you should not use `click` binding without **unbinding** of the previous handler. If you insert `alert("in click")` in your current code of the function which you bind, you will see that after every selection of the same row the `alert` function will be called many times (twice, three time and so on). So to fix your code you should **remove** any `click` binding inside of the `beforeSelectRow`. You bound already one `click` event handle one time at the beginning (see `$(".DeleteButton").button(...).click` inside of `gridComplete`).
7. Like I described above, you should add `type=\"button\"` in the HTML code fragment which you place in the `Option` column.
8. Because you set only one cell value, it is better to use `setCell` method instead of `setRowData` method.
9. You should increase the width of the `Options` column to see inserted buttons in one row in Google Chrome browser. In my modified version I used `width:98` instead of original `width:96`.
10. Some small changes in the HTML code is recommended to make the code a valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional or XHTML 1.0 Strict code. (see comments in the modified page)

Comment: To say that u r a gem Oleg would be a gross understatement. Thank u!